# Filename expansion from date ranges

Tags: bash, files, zsh, wildcards

Consider dates in the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format i.e. `‘YYYY-MM-DD’`, e.g. `2015-01-28`, and say we have a folder with files of the form:

```
AAAA_<date>_BBBB
```

I am looking for a glob pattern in **zsh** (or Bash) that I could use to specify files between **two** dates.

For example, say I want to copy files between `2014-12-15` and `2015-02-03`. Is there an easy way to build a glob expression to refer to files between those two dates (including them)?

#### The following may help (from [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)):

> An important exploitation of lexicographical ordering is expressed in
> the ISO 8601 date formatting scheme, which expresses a date as
> YYYY-MM-DD. This date ordering lends itself to straightforward
> computerized sorting of dates such that the sorting algorithm does not
> need to treat the numeric parts of the date string any differently
> from a string of non-numeric characters, and the dates will be sorted
> into chronological order.

Comment: No, that would even be really ugly and verbose with full-featured regex. Just loop and compare.

Comment: @jordanm I have udpated the question in case it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good you tagged the question with `zsh`, since in that shell you can use extensive [*glob qualifiers*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) including test done on file names:

```
$ ls -1 AAAA*
AAAA_2012-10-03_BBBB
AAAA_2014-12-28_BBBB
AAAA_2015-01-03_BBBB
AAAA_2015-02-03_BBBB
AAAA_2015-10-03_BBBB

$ d1='2014-12-15'
$ d2='2015-02-03'
$ print -l *(e:'[[ "${${REPLY#*_}%_*}" > "$d1" && "${${REPLY#*_}%_*}" < "$d2" ]]':)
AAAA_2014-12-28_BBBB
AAAA_2015-01-03_BBBB
```

Note that for the given date format you can perform simple string comparison.

I assumed here, that your files are named `AAAA_date_BBBB` as in the question and extracted the "date" part with parameter expansion. You would probably need to modify this code to get "date" in suitable way for your real case scenario.